# Creating a Canopy Height Model (CHM) image from a LAS file on Mac?

Tags: lidar, mac, batch, pdal, canopy-height-model

Main question: Is there a way of creating a Canopy Height Model from a LAS file using Mac (not [wine](https://www.winehq.org) etc)? I also would like to batch process a lot of LAS files the same way.

I should mention that I have tried PDAL with [writers.gdal](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html) through [docker](https://www.docker.com) where I managed to make a DTM and DSM. But then what? Is it possible to create a CHM with PDAL? I saw [lidar2dems](http://applied-geosolutions.github.io/lidar2dems/) but I'm not sure it would work on Mac.

Maybe there are more alternatives than PDAL?

Comment: You can use LasTools (I think) https://rapidlasso.com/2014/10/04/using-lastools-on-mac-os-x-with-wine/ not being a Mac user I can't verify the text. Is your LAS classified to at least ground/nonground? you need to create a ground raster (class 2,8 and possibly 9) and nonground height raster then subtract the ground from the nonground using QGIS raster calculator (or other package that works on Mac) consider where there is no vegetation or just noise and decide if you want 0 or NoData where the rasters are very similar before processing.

Comment: Why are you against using wine? Lastools runs fine using wine. More details here: https://rapidlasso.com/2014/10/04/using-lastools-on-mac-os-x-with-wine/. Additionally, here is a lastools article on generating CHMs: https://rapidlasso.com/2014/11/04/rasterizing-perfect-canopy-height-models-from-lidar/. If you have serious processing needs, spin up an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu using `lascanopy`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't have the economy to use rapidlassos license. Therefore that's not really an option for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with this solution with PDAL and GDAL:

First I used liblas to create LAS containing only ground points. Then I used [PDAL](http://pdal.io) similar to the ["Basic Example"](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html#basic-example) but with `output_type: max` to create a DTM from the terrain LAS and a DSM from the original LAS.

Then just [gdal_calc.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) with these to elevation models to get a DHM.

```
gdal_calc.py -A DSM.tif -B DTM.tif --outfile=CHM.tif --calc="A-B" --NoDataValue=0
```

Comment: Hey is output_type: max really "comparable" to so called DSM or DTM? Is it a particular type of DSM or DTM? This answer is nice, because it allows staying within Python.

Comment: Actually I've changed it to "idw" now.

Comment: Okay, yet this doesn't answer my question about what kind of DSM or DTM you do? Whether it's based on some standard or whether it's your own take on them?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I create one model which takes all the ground points from the LAS file and then another one which takes canopy points.

Comment: Have you tried importing the resulting .tif to QGIS does it import? I tried doing the same using the GDAL for Python library and I get "invalid provider" error.

Comment: Yes, and it works fine in QGIS.

Comment: How do you know where the outputted Z coordinates are located? I tried using this, but noticed that now the output points align by the given resolution in writers.gdal, even if the input points would not align in that resolution. Thus if there's some "max Z" point, then I'm not sure, which X/Y it corresponds to in the original data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: The output .tif is a matrix, which has z-values at matrix positions [x,y]? Assuming resolution 3 and origin centered data, then e.g. [1,1] has that z-coordinate which is at [0:3,0:3]. Yet if there were other points in the area [0:3,0:3] of original data, then this z-coordinate is the largest in that area, but it has lost precision in x/y, that is, at which x/y is that max located precisely. It's e.g. the vector (1.2,1.5,z), but the output doesn't reveal this.

Answer (score 4):

1) You can use the the little known [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) (Mac version, [Download Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml)), developed for the Java platform (Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 8.0 or higher installed) and Open Source (GNU General Public License version 3)

Look at [Working with LiDAR data in Whitebox GAT](https://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/working-with-lidar-data-in-whitebox-gat/)

[image]

2) You can also use

- GRASS GIS ([GRASS GIS for Mac](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads)), see [Wiki: LIDAR](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR), [r.in.lidar](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.in.lidar.html) and [GRASS r.in.lidar tool generates incomplete rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187165/grass-r-in-lidar-tool-generates-incomplete-rasters)
- or [Cloud Compare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/) (Mac OS X port: [MMac OS X: CloudCompare](https://asmaloney.com/software/))

There are other solutions if you know Python or R ([lidR
 package: Compute a digital canopy model (DCM)](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/grid_canopy) for example)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what has been mentioned above, [SPDLib](http://www.spdlib.org) is another powerful set of open-source tools for processing LiDAR data (LAS files). It is cross-platform and supports [Mac](http://www.spdlib.org/doku.php?id=spdlib:general:installation:macosx).

The [spdinterp](http://www.spdlib.org/doku.php?id=spdlib:users:commands:spdinterp) program has the capability to generate Canopy Height Models as well as DTMs and DSMs.